# Run a command on a SSH screen through SSH with phpseclib

Tags: php, ssh, gnu-screen, phpseclib

I have a PHP script that starts a detached screen through SSH:

```
$ssh->exec("screen -m -d -S ".$user);
```

I now need to execute a command  in that screen without being in that screen. I have the code that does that, which I have tested through a SSH client, but when I try to use it with the phpseclib exec command, it does not work. This is the code that works:

```
screen -S ".$user." -X stuff "cd minecraft/servers/".$user."/;sh start.sh $(printf '\r')"
```

And this is it in the PHP script:

`$ssh->exec("screen -S ".$user." -X stuff \"cd minecraft/servers/".$user."/;sh start.sh $(printf '\r')\"");`

I attempted to escape the extra double quotes in the code.

Is there anything I can do to make this work through PHP? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm... create two bash script, first: create screen with `user` parameter with name f.e. `run_screen`, second: tester for SSH client with `user` parameter with name f.e. `run_test`. Run first script, `$ssh->exec('[full_path]/run_screen ' . $user);` and second: `$ssh->exec('[full_path]/run_test ' . $user);`. All system commands moves to bash scripts. You can write scrips in bash?

Comment: I am not completely sure how to make these bash files, could you link me to a resource or something?

Comment: look here: [http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, a variation of what you said worked. I used the user parameter. Thanks

Comment: I'll add an answer with comment content, others can they use, select please as solution if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...

create please two bash script, first: create screen with user parameter with name f.e. `run_screen`, second: tester for SSH client with `user` parameter with name f.e. `run_test`.

Run first script:

```
$ssh->exec('[full_path]/run_screen ' . $user);
```

and second:

```
$ssh->exec('[full_path]/run_test ' . $user);
```

`bash` syntax is here [bash syntax](http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial)

Sure that the user of server (f.e. Apache) has permissions to run scripts.